# Can I swap out caddie tray to use hard drive with another server?

Tags: hard-drive

Supporting legacy (Sun Fire X4100) equipment, looking to purchase drives of higher capacity and/or get better pricing by not limiting my selection to former-Sun hard drives.

1. I've been told that X4100 is compatible with newer Sun 300G and 600G drives, despite being listed as a max of 4 x 146G. (at time of EOL)
2. I am guessing that replacement hard drives need not be Sun-specific, because other brands, such as Dell use the same Seagate part # on their 146G - looks identical with the exception of caddie tray.

Perhaps I could replace the caddie tray to use a non-Sun drive in the X4100. I know it must be 2.5", SAS, 22-pin of course.

Is there anything else I need to look out for?

- brand? - I know X4100 works with Seagate/Hitachi/Fujitsu. Is this because of drivers on the firmware (in which case other brands may not work), or would they typically all use the same interface? (in which case brand would probably not matter)
- revision? - I have Seagate SAS 10K.1, but not sure what the `.1` is referring to.. Would a Seagate 10K.4 introduce a compatibility problem, or is it the same interface?
- capacity? - I've been informed that there is no limit on the server or controller, is this the typical case with server equipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried it and it worked. Turns out new revisions of SAS are compatible with hardware supporting only an older revision of SAS. (though they do not get the higher throughput supported) I'm not aware of any capacity ceiling on older SAS hardware.

I did stick with the same brand Seagate, though I wouldn't be surprised if any brand of SAS drive would work.